# UISegmentControl and UITableViewController animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can I animate my "removal of tableviewitems" when the user changes between segments in the UISegmentControl?

The behaviour should be similar to "Missed/All" calls in the Phone App.

Answer (score 2):

The deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: and insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: will  provide the animation for you.

If you need to perform a more complex operation (inserts and deletes), you start a block. similar to a UIView animation block:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

//add and delete

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Bear in mind you will need to update the model to reflect the changes in the table.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView can be sent a message: [deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
The withRowAnimation argument determines the type of animatio that will be used in removing the cell.

I don't know if any of those animations match the missed/all functionality exactly though. If they don't, I'm guessing you will have to set up an animation to collapse the height of the cells before removing them.